# VBA find and write functions

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I am trying to solve is I am looking to write a function to find a text string in a different workbook than I am writing to. The goal is to find the text in document A (not the source of the code. Just the database of the information), write an `"P"` in a box under that correlates with the text in the active sheet, document B. Right now I just want to search document A and write the `"P"` to a defined cell in document B.

Note: I left out a few of the other functions to try and simplify what I am posting 
Note: The code doesn't show up perfectly on here. I am very new to posting. Sorry for the inconvenience.

My code is adapted from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

My code so far:

```
 Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dataBase As Workbook
    Dim Config As String

    'This makes it so the database will not visibly open
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'this saves the full path name as well as the file name for the Route Chart template/open file
    NegsFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    'the getFile function opens up a file explorer in order to select the database. the line
    'below the call for that is the location of it on my computer, and simply there for testing
    'purposes
    Config = GetFile("Select the Config file")
    'Config = "C:\Users\Z003CPYE\Desktop\CP256_M1_Rev2.0.xlsm"

    'this is where we call to the functions that actually grab the data.
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    Call WriteInputs(Config)
    Call FindRoutes(Config)
    Call FindAddress(Config)

    'I do not really know why this is done, but everything I read online said to do this
    'if you set it to false.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFile(prompt As String) As String
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

    'This opens the file browser, and filters it for .xlsx and .xlsm files only.
    'NOTE: it recieves prompt when called as an argument, and returns the string
    'of the file that is selected's path.
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX;*.XLSM), *.XLSX;*.XLSM", Title:=prompt)

    'This is from the function Ifsafd saw online, I believe it is for the exit/close
    'and cancel button being clicked
    If fNameAndPath = False Then
    Call stopAllMacros
    End If

    GetFile = fNameAndPath

End Function

Sub stopAllMacros()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End
End Sub

Sub FindAddress(Config As String)
    Dim NegativesPath As Workbook
    Dim cfg As Workbook
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim Page$, Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$


    Set NegativesPath = ActiveWorkbook
    Set cfg = Workbooks.Open(Config)

    'The text for which to search.
    Txt = "1E Sig"
    'The path to the workbook in which to search.
    MyPath = "C:\Users\z003njcy\Desktop\"
    'The name of the workbook in which to search.
    MyWB = "CP256_M1_Rev2.0.xlsm"

    'If an error occurs, use the error handling routine at the end of this file.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Turn off screen updating, and then open the target workbook.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'Search for the specified text in master file
    Set GCell = cfg.Worksheets("Location Input").Cells.Find(Txt)

    'Record the address of the data, along with the date, in sheet5 B4.
    With Project.Worksheets.Range("B4")
        .Value = Txt
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = "P"
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Offset(1, 1).Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Close the data workbook, without saving any changes, and turn screen updating back on.
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

    'Error Handling section.
ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    'Common error #1: file path or workbook name is wrong.
    Case 1004
    Range("D10:E11").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "The workbook " & MyWB & " could not be found in the path" & vbCrLf & MyPath & "."


    Exit Sub

    'Common error #2: the specified text wasn't in the target workbook.
    Case 9, 91
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MySheet).Range("D10:E11").ClearContents
    Workbooks(MyWB).Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "The value " & Txt & " was not found."
    Exit Sub

    'General case: turn screenupdating back on, and exit.
    Case Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
    End Select

End Sub
```